# Java IDEA SELENIUM не могу импортировать класс

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

[image: вMaven]

[image: Сама проблема]

[image: без Maven]

Добрый день не могу импортировать класс если проект собирается на Maven ,если без него все хорошо ,что не так я делаю?

Answer (score 0):

`<dependency>` нужно обернуть в `<dependencies>`, а у вас он в `<dependency>`

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
     <version>1.4</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: заработалоооо..спасибо)